# making a custom (tf.function) function 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow

I am trying to calculate a 2D array of a function of variables x, y as a tf.function. The function is fairly complicated and i want to make a 2d array of this function where x and y take a list of values (tf.linspace). Ive tried inputing the relevant arguments for such a function, here is what it looks like

```
@tf.function
def function_matrix(xi, xf, yi, yf, num , some_other_args):
    
    #part1
    M=np.zeros((num, num))
    xlist=tf.linspace(xi, xf, num)
    ylist=tf.linspace(yi, yf, num)
    
    #part2
    for x in range(num):
         for y in range(num):
             M[x,y]=some_complicated_function(xlist[x], ylist[y], some_other_args)     #this is also a @tf.function
    
    return (M)
```

The problem I'm encountering is that within a tf.function, if I try to access elements of an array like xlist[x], the result is a `Tensor("strided_slice:0", shape=(), dtype=float64)`. So when passing this value in some_complicated_function, I get an error "setting an array element with a sequence". No such error occurs if function_matrix is not a tf.function. Could someone help with this? as to where I could be going wrong? Or any alternative way I could calculate the 2D matrix of a fairly complicated function?
Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

**What I've tried**:
Part 1 runs fine, If I return xlist as the output of a function, I get a normal array, `tf.Tensor( [the_array_here], shape=(num,), dtype=float64)`. Similarly if the  the output is xlist[index], I get `tf.Tensor( [the_element_here], shape=(), dtype=float64)`. But is I try to print xlist[index] from within the function, I get `Tensor("strided_slice:0", shape=(), dtype=float64)`. So I am concluding that somehow tf is treating xlist[index] as placeholder of somekind. But I dont know why...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ooh nice question! `tensorflow` really doesn't like the `for` loops, it's `python` code that can't be automatically converted to a `tensorflow` `graph representation`. The way to implement this, is to generate the grid you want to operate on in a tensor. Let's say:

```
xlist=[1,2] # this is a tf.Tensor
ylist=[1,2] # this is a tf.Tensor
```

then, using `tf.meshgrid`, you should construct `xylist`:

```
xylist=[[1,1], [1,2], [2,1], [2,2]] # this is a tf.Tensor
```

and then use `tf.map_fn` to apply your function to each pair.

```
M = tf.map_fn(some_complicated_function, xylist)
M = tf.reshape(M, (...))
```

Note that if `some_complicated_function` contains any non `tensorflow` code (or code that cannot be automatically converted), like using `numpy`, `pandas`, `pillow`..., you can wrap it in a `tf.py_function` - but now that that kind of defeats the purpose of converting your function into a `tf.function`. (EDIT: I see now you say: `# this is also a tf.function`, which means you don't have to wrap it in a `tf.py_function`)

You can also include the `extra_args` by appending *to each pair* in `xylist` (yes each pair, even though they are constant).

TL;DR: use `tf.map_fn` instead of nested `for` loops.

Comment: Good answer. I would suggest using `tf.meshgrid` instead of `stack` and `concatenate` though.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it existed but forgot the name :D included it

Comment: Also, for `extra_args`, if they don't change during the iteration, currying `functools.partial` or a `lambda` seems appropriate.